# /usr/bin/time command -v not working

Tags: time

I know many questions have been asked/answered about the `time` command, but mine still seems to be not working. I have been doing like everyone suggests, and using `/usr/bin/time`, which seems to work, but every time I trying using `/usr/bin/time -v` or `/usr/bin/time -verbose`, it spits out an error saying

`/usr/bin/time: illegal option -- v
usage: time [-lp] command.`

In an ideal world, I would have used `tstime`, but that's not working either as it says `tstime: command not found`. My bash is 3.2. I'm just really not sure what's going on...

Comment: `-v` is a GNU extension, do you have a GNU version of `time`?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @EricRenouf When I run `gcc --version`, I get `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix` I thought that I had the GNU version...if not, how would I go about getting it?

Comment: @DravSloan OSX Yosemite Version 10.10.4.

Comment: @jacob if I run `/usr/bin/time --version` I get `GNU time 1.7` so perhaps you'll have a similar result, if not you likely do not have GNU's version.  I don't use OSX myself so don't really know how to get the GNU version, except that people seem to talk about homebrew for such tasks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac OS X doesn't ship with the GNU stack. You have "BSD Time" `time.c,v 1.9`. You can verify this by typing:

```
strings /usr/bin/time | grep c,v
```

BSD time doesn't support `--verbose`, but it does support `/usr/bin/time -lp`:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -lp echo hi
hi
real         0.02
user         0.00
sys          0.00
    700416  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
       174  page reclaims
         6  page faults
         0  swaps
         7  block input operations
         1  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         9  voluntary context switches
         1  involuntary context switches
$
```

Which seems to provide a lot of the output that GNU `time` provides with `--verbose`:

```
ubuntu@sandbox:~$ /usr/bin/time --verbose echo hi
hi
    Command being timed: "echo hi"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 66%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1804
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 78
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 3
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
ubuntu@sandbox:~$
```

If you really want `--verbose`, you can install GNU `time` with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
$ brew install gnu-time
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gnu-time-1.7.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring gnu-time-1.7.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/gnu-time/1.7: 8 files, 80K

$ gtime --verbose echo hi
hi
    Command being timed: "echo hi"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 16%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2785280
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 6
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 279
    Voluntary context switches: 2
    Involuntary context switches: 6
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 1
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```